# Wizard/Workflow application using React

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a workflow/wizard type application using react. I need to show/hide react components based on certain conditions. Currently I have too many if/else in my main react component. I want to keep it simpler and saw this blog where the component decides if it should be shown or not based on the props passed(https://css-tricks.com/the-magic-of-react-based-multi-step-forms/). This keeps the code cleaner and we don't need many if/else in parent component.

```
render() {
    if (this.props.currentStep !== 1) { // Prop: The current step
      return null
    }
}
```

I want to know if this is the right way to do it or shall I use ternay operator on the main component/container or if there is another better way?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at doing something like this:

```
render() {
    const {currentStep} = this.props;
    return (
        <>
        {currentStep === 1 &&
            <SomeElement />
        }
        </>
    )
}
```